# How can I get the data tables value too? when i click update. I want to update my textbox too but my data table only updates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the image when I run the codes
[image]

Here is my Controller:

```
using ajaxcrud.DB.Core;
using ajaxcrud.DB.Data;
using ajaxcrud.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ajaxcrud.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ajaxcrudContext db = new ajaxcrudContext();
       

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult getOrderList()
        {
            var order = (from s in db.Orders

                            select new OrderFormModel
                            {
                                Id = s.Id,
                                FirstName = s.FirstName,
                                MiddleName = s.MiddleName,
                                LastName = s.LastName,
                                //OrderNumber = Convert.ToString(s.OrderNumber),
                                OrderNumber = s.OrderNumber,
                                OrderName = s.OrderName
                            }).ToList();

            return Json(new { data = order.ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //public ActionResult saveOrder(int? id)
        //{
        //    var model = new OrderFormModel();

        //    if (id != null)
        //        model.Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        //    model = PrepareOrderFormModel(model);

        //    return View(model);
        //}

        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var model = new OrderFormModel();

            if (id != null)
                model.Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);

            model = PrepareOrderFormModel(model);

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult saveOrder(OrderFormModel model)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (model.Id > 0)
                    {
                        //dito mo lagay edit mo if greater than 0 ibig sabigin may pinasa kang Id so papasok sya as edit
                        using (var db = new ajaxcrudContext())
                        {
                            var orderUpdate = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

                            orderUpdate.Id = model.Id;
                            orderUpdate.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                            orderUpdate.MiddleName = model.MiddleName;
                            orderUpdate.LastName = model.LastName;
                            orderUpdate.OrderName = model.OrderName;
                            orderUpdate.OrderNumber = model.OrderNumber;
                            db.Orders.AddOrUpdate(orderUpdate);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            //return Json(orderUpdate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                            return RedirectToAction("index", new { model.Id });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //eto naman is for add
                        using (var db = new ajaxcrudContext())
                        {
                            var order = new Order
                            {
                                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                                MiddleName = model.MiddleName,
                                LastName = model.MiddleName,
                                OrderNumber = model.OrderNumber,
                                OrderName = model.OrderName,
                            };
                            db.Orders.Add(order);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return Json(order, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", ex.Message);
                }
            }
            model = PrepareOrderFormModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        public OrderFormModel PrepareOrderFormModel(OrderFormModel model)
        {

            //var Orders = db.Orders.ToList();

            //model.Orders = Orders.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            //{
            //    Text = x.LastName,
            //    Value = x.Id.ToString()
            //});

            if (model.Id > 0)
            {
                var order = db.Orders.Find(model.Id);

                model.FirstName = order.FirstName;
                model.LastName = order.LastName;
                model.MiddleName = order.MiddleName;
                model.OrderNumber = order.OrderNumber;
                model.OrderName = order.OrderName;
            }
            return model;
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(OrderFormModel model)
        {
            if (model.Id > 0)
            {
                var orderId = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

                db.Orders.Remove(orderId);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@using ajaxcrud.Models
@model ajaxcrud.Models.OrderFormModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<form>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "firstname", @name = "firstname" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "middlename", @name = "middlename" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "lastname", @name = "lastname" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.OrderNumber, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OrderNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ordernumber", @name = "ordernumber" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.OrderName, new { @class = "form-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OrderName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ordername", @name = "ordername" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnSubmit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<table id="EmptyBox" class="display table table-striped" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Order Number</th>
            <th>Order Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

@*<a href="@Url.Action("add", "order")" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add Order</a>*@

<script type="text/javascript">
    var table;
     $(function () { //load data table
         table = $('#EmptyBox').DataTable({
            "ajax": "@Url.Action("getOrderList", "home")",
             "columns": [
                { "data": "FirstName" },
                { "data": "MiddleName" },
                { "data": "LastName" },
                { "data": "OrderNumber" },
                { "data": "OrderName" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onclick='edit(" + full.Id + ")'><i class='fas fa-user-edit'></i></button> <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='del(" + full.Id + ")'><i class='fas fa-user-edit'></i></button>"

                    }
                }
             ]
         });
     });

    // eto  is function papuntang controller na kung saan kinukuha nya yung  onclick na edit
    function edit(id) {
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("index", "home")?id=" + id;
    }

    function del(id) {
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("delete", "home")?id=" + id;
    }

    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () { //submit textbox value to data table
        //var order = {};
        //order.FirstName = $('#firstname').val();
        //order.MiddleNAme = $('#middlename').val();
        //order.LastName = $('#lastname').val();
        //order.OrderNumber = $('#ordername').val();
        //order.OrderName = $('#ordername').val();


        var order = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("saveOrder", "Home")",
            data: order,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //alert('Successfully saved!');
                //table();
                table.html(data);
                console.log(data)
                //table.clear();
                //table.ajax.reload();
                //table.draw();
                
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

I want to update datatable as same as my values in my textbox.
I try to do ModelState.Clear in my modelstate to remove the textbox but It doesn't work.
My problem is when I click update my datatable updates but the values in textbox didn't update. Please help me resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to update..value of textbox to database or database value bind to text boxes..?

Comment: when i click update the data table updates but the textbox value didn't change.

Comment: update or save...?

Comment: update and save in one button

Comment: when you are updating ..what do you want to update in textboxes ..?

Comment: same as data table data

Comment: did not get yr point..already data come from text box and update to data table and you want to update back text box with data table data...both data are same ...orgin and target...so what do you want to achieve?

Comment: is there any way to just only clear the textbox when I click button update in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write clear text box value function on submit button click event (ajax call's success event) in jquery like as below :

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () { //submit textbox value to data table

    var order = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("saveOrder", "Home")",
        data: order,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //alert('Successfully saved!');
            //table();
            table.html(data);
            console.log(data)
            //table.clear();
            //table.ajax.reload();
            //table.draw();

           // Clear text box values
            $('#firstname').val("")
            $('#middlename').val("")
            // clear another fields here                
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});
```